# Apache2 reads HTML fine but returns "could not connect to localhost" for PHP

Tags: macos, apache, apache2

I'm trying to setup Apache and PHP on OS X Mountain Lion (10.8.3), but I'm not sure how to fix this issue. I pinged 127.0.0.1 and got 100% received. Also, the default "It works!" page shows (it's HTML). I'm not a server expert, so please let me know if there's any info I should post.

```
$ apachectl -v
Server version: Apache/2.2.22 (Unix)
Server built:   Dec  9 2012 18:57:18

$ php -v
PHP 5.3.15 with Suhosin-Patch (cli) (built: Aug 24 2012 17:45:44)
Copyright (c) 1997-2012 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.3.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2012 Zend Technologies
```

Thanks!

Comment: Check your PHP.INI... it could be that your PHP setup doesn't check the correct paths (in other words: has another path configured than where your html and php files reside).